# API to put shirt on 3d avatar

Tags: three.js, 3d, babylonjs, avatar, avatar-generation

I created avatar 3d model (.glb) able to run from browser. I want user to upload the shirt(image)
and avatar dress should be updated accordingly.

I tried various options mixamo, readyplayer.me etc but they do not have option to update the avatar with custom dress, Is there any API for any open source solution for this. Pls suggest

Thanks
vijay

Comment: I am trying with the frameworks  three.js and Babylon.js where i can upload the .glb file (human avatar) and change dress colors. Is there any readymade package for this pls let me know,

Answer (score 0):

more info is needed but based on what is provided it sounds like you have means to extract material texture from photograph. Once you have the texture, then it would come down to matching UV layout and just applying the new texture to the material. this process would be the same in three.js, babylon.js or any other 3d library you use.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.